# Why javax validation not working in DTO class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

I am trying to learn the spring boot. And, I am stuck on the form validation process. I have followed the process as instructed  [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/).

Here is my controller class

```
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class TalentCategoryController {

    @GetMapping("talent-category")
    public ModelAndView create(CreateTalentCategoryRequest talentCategory) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("talent-category/create");
        model.addObject("talentCategory", talentCategory);
        return model ; 
    }

    @Autowired
    TalentCategoryService talentCategoryService ; 
     
    @RequestMapping(path="talent-category", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})
    public ModelAndView store(@Valid @ModelAttribute CreateTalentCategoryRequest talentCategory, BindingResult result) {
        // result.hasErrors is false
        if(result.hasErrors()) { 
            System.out.println("Validation working");
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();            
            model.setViewName("talent-category/create");
            return model; 
        }
        System.out.println("Validation not working");
        talentCategoryService.store();
        return null ; 
    }
     
}
```

DTO class :

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class CreateTalentCategoryRequest {
    
    @NotBlank(message="Cannot be empty")
    @Size(min=10, max=30)
    private String name ; 
    
    @NotBlank(message="Cannot be empty")
    private String status  ; 

    @NotBlank(message="Cannot be empty")
    private String approved ; 
    
    @NotBlank(message="Cannot be empty")
    private String sort_order ;

}
```

View :

```
<form th:object="${talentCategory}" name="create-talent-category" method="POST" th:action="@{/talent-category}">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input th:field="*{name}" type="text"  class="form-control form-control-sm" id="name" placeholder="Category Name" />
                <p class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}"></p>
                
             </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sort_order">Sort Order</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="sort_order" placeholder="Eg : 1" />
             </div>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="col-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="status">Status</label>
                 <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                    <option selected>Choose...</option>
                    <option value="1">Active</option>
                    <option value="0">Passive</option>
                 </select>
             </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="approved">Approved</label>
                 <select name="approved" id="approved" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                    <option selected>Choose...</option>
                    <option value="1">Yes</option>
                    <option value="0">No</option>
                 </select>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <button name="create" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Create</button>
        </div>
    </div>
 </form>
```

When a form is submitted with all the fields empty, the request is not redirect to the form(prints validation not working in console).

Comment: Please add an example for which validation is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using spring version 2.3+ , make sure you have following dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. You save my day.